# SVN overwrites local copy of XML file rather than displaying a conflict

Tags: svn, windows-7, tortoisesvn

I have an SVN repository managing our project and we have a config file for the app that has been committed to the base so that every developer can get the format. He/she is then required to modify that file to match their system's settings. I recently committed my copy of the config file (by mistake) and on the next update, everyone else was automatically updated to my copy rather than SVN declaring a conflicted state. The following line particularly intrigues me:

```
<Address>http://192.168.1.136:8080/FeatureServer</Address>
```

This is my local IP address and each developer has to modify this line to point it to their IP address. Once I committed my file, SVN now just updates everyone else's config files to my copy on an 'Update'. Why is that so? Is it because this is not a code file and SVN somehow knows it ? I do get conflicts in code files so I don't think SVN is somehow messed up. What's special in this case?

I use TortoiseSVN 1.7.4 over Windows 7 on a 64 bit machine.

Thanks

Comment: Are you certain that the other developers had modified their copies of the file?  Maybe they hadn't got around to doing that yet, in which case there would be no conflict.  If they had, then it would be interesting to see an 'svn log -v' of the file in their workspace. BTW, if you can't rearrange things so that the repo contains just a template that you copy and modify to customise, then it's probably a good idea to 'svn lock' this file so that it's harder for someone to accidentally clobber it in the future.

Comment: I think they did modify their files and still got their local copies updated. 'svn log -v' spits out a giant log file of the entire repo. Am I looking for something specific in that log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out if the developer hasn't changed the file on his/her end, they will receive the update from the server. A conflict does show up when I change my copy and then do an update.